# Вывод информации из базы данных

Tags: база-данных, php, html

Мне нужно сделать такое:
нажимаю я на ссылку или кнопку и после я перехожу на страницу , где буду выводить информацию из БД.
Rак сделать этот переход кроме как `<form action="display.php"></form>`?

Comment: Ну php из коробки поддерживает редиректы:
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php

Comment: Можно еще на js сделать: http://javascript.ru/window-location

А вообще, почему вдруг понадобилось делать редирект из формы не с помощью action? Я имею в виду, что возможно в этом нет нужды т.к. это неправильный подход.

Comment: нет мне не с помощью формы надо, а вообще как-нибудь иначче

Comment: <pre><code><?php
     // какой-то код;
     echo "<a href='handler.php?action='$your_data' >
    нажми на меня</a>";
    ?>
</code></pre>